# Open list of adult websites for child internet

Tags: whitelist

Looking for any open and dynamic list(blacklist) of 
adult,dangerous,+18,sucide,drugs etc web resources
 to filter it in intranet for children security in internet

Comment: DNS services provide this for free. Keeping up with the infinite list is too resource intensive to maintain in a text file.

Comment: Honestly, these days, when somebody wants to see something on the Internet, there are always ways to do it. Initiating an honest parental and two-sided discussion with your children is far more effective. That works if they're not too young. However, if they're too young for this discussion, they're probably too young to be left online alone.

Comment: Trying to block [all things of categories x,y,z,...] on the Internet is, for all practical purposes, impossible with blacklisting. If you *really* want to restrict your child's view of the Internet, you should use whitelisting (permitting traffic *only* to select *approved* sites/services). However, this quickly becomes a management overhead nightmare as they grow older and have legitimate educational and developmental needs to broaden their view of the Internet. Besides, they'll just end up browsing whatever you don't want them to see on their phone anyway.

Answer (score 1):

OpenDNS is a DNS service provider that will likely be able to help you with this. There is a free version that will be able to perform the parental controls that you require.

This provides a list of known websites that it will automatically block for all devices. You would configure it by adding it as the DNS provider from the router level. Although this isn't 100% effective as a user can set a static DNS at the device level and would be able to visit those websites.

The only 100% fool proof way of performing this is to install a web proxy appliance at the border of your house network and you would then be able to block the traffic.

Below is a blurb from there website, which I am not affiliated with nor do I work with them (or use them).

> A faster and more reliable Internet Choose the world’s leading DNS
>   service and free your network of frustrating, intermittent Internet
>   outages and make your Internet noticeably faster. Flexible parental
>   controls that protect every Internet-connected device in your home,
>   instantly When you set up OpenDNS Home on your router, your settings
>   take effect across everything on your home network. In addition to
>   computers, this includes your kids’ Xbox, Playstation, Wii, DS, iPad,
>   and even their iPhone.

http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/